# Spring/Flex on Websphere

Tags: apache-flex, hibernate, spring, deployment, websphere

I have a simple hibernate/spring/flex project. The project was developed under apache tomcat6. Can anyone point me how to proceed to deploy it on IBM webshphere v6.1? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it should work if you project is J2EE 1.4 and JDK 5 compatible.

The most important step is to wrap an EAR around your WAR.

And on think I remember (I have such a port some time ago), is that you will need to change the Class loader order of the WAR!! in WAS to "parent last" (else you will get a lot of strange errors do to not compatible classes.)

And then you need to go form one problem to the next (sorry).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did it. A lot of work on jars compatibility. Next time i'll be posting about it in my blog. Another issue also is about database connectivity. We must define the jndi connection on Websphere and then use it in webApplicationContext.xml ...